# Permanent residence card Germany

Tags: resident-permit, blue-card

There is a question in my permanent residence form:

> Haben Sie Pflichtbeiträge zur gesetzlichen Rentenversicherung oder Aufwendungen auf
> vergleichbare Leistungen einer Versicherungs- oder Versorgungseinrichtung entrichtet?
>
> > Have you paid compulsory contributions to statutory pension insurance or expenses for comparable benefits from an insurance or pension scheme?

I didn't quite understand it. Can somebody can explain this?
(I have a blue card and have been working at that job from the very first day.)

Comment: Can you provide your translation, it isn’t clear from your question exactly what you don’t understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have a blue card and have been working at that job from the very first day.

The answer is then **yes** (ja), you have been paying contributions to the Pension funds.

This is booked from your pay each month.

The amount of months determines if you are eligible for permanent residence.

Answer (score 0):

Go on this website:

https://www.eservice-drv.de/SelfServiceWeb/

Then select the option that says "Versicherungsverlauf" and then order it. That is the document you need. An ofc, don't forget to say 'yes' if the number of months in that document is not zero ;)

If the number of months on there are less than what you need, you can attach the payslips from your employer from this year.